# API integration error HTTParty

Tags: ruby, api, runtime-error, httparty

I'm learning how to work with HTTParty and API and I'm having an issue with my code.

```
Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize': the scheme http does not accept registry part: :80 (or bad hostname?)
```

I've tried using `debug_output STDOUT` both as an argument to my method and after including HTTParty to have a clue but with no success. Nothing gets displayed:

```
     require 'httparty'

      class LolObserver
        include HTTParty
        default_timeout(1) #timeout after 1 second

        attr_reader :api_key, :playerid
        attr_accessor :region
        def initialize(region,playerid,apikey)
          @region = region_server(region)
          @playerid = playerid
          @api_key = apikey
        end

        def region_server(region)
          case region
          when "euw"
            self.class.base_uri "https://euw.api.pvp.net"
            self.region = "EUW1"
          when "na"
            self.class.base_uri "https://na.api.pvp.net"
            self.region = "NA1"
          end
        end

        def handle_timeouts
          begin
            yield
          #Timeout::Error, is raised if a chunk of the response cannot be read within the read_timeout.
          #Timeout::Error, is raised if a connection cannot be created within the open_timeout.
          rescue Net::OpenTimeout, Net::ReadTimeout
            #todo
          end
        end

        def base_path
          "/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo"
        end

        def current_game_info
          handle_timeouts do
            url = "#{ base_path }/#{region}/#{playerid}?api_key=#{api_key}"
            puts '------------------------------'
            puts url
            HTTParty.get(url,:debug_output => $stdout)
          end
        end

      end
```

I verified my URL which is fine so I'm lost as to where the problem is coming from.

I tested with a static `base_uri` and it doesn't change anything.

The odd thing is when I do:

```
 HTTParty.get("https://euw.api.pvp.net/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo/EUW1/randomid?api_key=myapikey")
```

Everything is working fine and I'm getting a response.

Comment: Why is that ? how can i use the base_uri class method without it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTParty doesn't seem to like the way you set your base_uri.

Unless you need it to be like that just add another `attr_reader` called `domain` and it will work.

```
require 'httparty'

class LolObserver
 include HTTParty
 default_timeout(1) #timeout after 1 second

 attr_reader :api_key, :playerid, :domain
 attr_accessor :region
 def initialize(region,playerid,apikey)
   @region = region_server(region)
   @playerid = playerid
   @api_key = apikey
 end

 def region_server(region)
   case region
   when "euw"
     @domain = "https://euw.api.pvp.net"
     self.region = "EUW1"
   when "na"
     @domain = "https://na.api.pvp.net"
     self.region = "NA1"
   end
 end

 def handle_timeouts
   begin
     yield
   #Timeout::Error, is raised if a chunk of the response cannot be read within the read_timeout.
   #Timeout::Error, is raised if a connection cannot be created within the open_timeout.
   rescue Net::OpenTimeout, Net::ReadTimeout
     #todo
   end
 end

 def base_path
   "/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo"
 end

 def current_game_info
   handle_timeouts do
     url = "#{domain}/#{ base_path }/#{region}/#{playerid}?api_key=#{api_key}"
     puts '------------------------------'
     puts url
     HTTParty.get(url,:debug_output => $stdout)
   end
 end

 end
```

Comment: hey ! thanks for the help. Indeed it's working. I'm getting the fix that you did and it make sens. 
What doesn't make sense to me is why the way i did it doesn't work because after instantiating my class i can do :
`test = LolObserver.new(x,y,z)
 test.class.base_uri`

And this will always give me the proper base_uri. So i don't get where it's breaking exactly ( i mean it's here obviously but i doesn't make sens to me )

Comment: YW. I was seeing the same thing when I was testing it. When I pulled up the HTTParty docs they set that value differently without the self.class which lead me to think that is what was causing the issue. Glad I was able get it to work for you. Mark me correct if there is nothing else I can help with